# CSS3 - Flex wrap not working on IOS 10.1.1 Safari & Chrome

Tags: ios, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flex wrap and min-width: 50% to dynamic grid layout where single cells occupy all width. The problem is that it's not working correctly in iOS 10.1.1 (iPhone 5c) Safari and Chrome - the display is not grid-like, but a horizontal layout. In desktop Chrome (Ubuntu) and Android Chrome is working fine.

Jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9dscc1Lq/

Code:

```
<style>

body {
    width: 300px;
}

.tabs {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.tab {
    border: 1px solid #3A3A3A;
    color: #929292;
    min-width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 0;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>

<div class="tabs">
    <div class="gwt-HTML tab">1</div>
    <div class="gwt-HTML tab">2</div>
    <div class="gwt-HTML tab">3</div>
    <div class="gwt-HTML tab">4</div>
    <div class="gwt-HTML tab">5</div>
</div>
```

Expected layout (correct):

[image]

iOS behavior (incorrect):
[image]

Please advise!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`min-width` doesn't work as intended on iOS, use `flex-basis` like this `flex: 1 1 50%;`

Src: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136041

Also, when using prefixed properties, you should always put them before the unprefixed version.

```css
.tabs {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tab {
  border: 1px solid #3A3A3A;
  color: #929292;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 50%;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="gwt-HTML tab">1</div>
  <div class="gwt-HTML tab">2</div>
  <div class="gwt-HTML tab">3</div>
  <div class="gwt-HTML tab">4</div>
  <div class="gwt-HTML tab">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I also applied that pattern to other flex layouts and it worked, i just didn't know that min-width was breaking flex in IOS.

Comment: I'm trying that but it's not working =( it puts all the 3 columns together instead of the last one at the bottom =( iphone 5s 8.3 here

Comment: @Cheshire As this answer the `min-width` issue, you seems to talk about a _height_ issue. Please post a question of your own, with a minimal working code snippet that cause your issue, and we try help you with that. If you want, you can notify me here with a link.

Comment: @LGSon no no, it's not about height, I'm trying to do the same as the OP, the last item should be the same width as both, but seems that with iOS 8.3 with iphone 5s is not working.

Comment: @Cheshire I need to see the code snippet to be able to say something.

Comment: @LGSon I copied this answer CSS's. Android, chrome... it's looking fine, but not in that version of iOS iphone. Anyways, will try to open now a question

Comment: @Cheshire What if you add `width: 50%` ...?